# Create directory issue

Tags: php, forms

can you help me to solve this problem?
I have this:

```
<form action="setari_cont.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src="img/defaultavatar.jpg" width="70"/>
<input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Upload">
</form>
```

and this

```
if(isset($_FILES['profilepic']))
{
    if(($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") ||
       ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || 
       ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))
    {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
        mkdir('userdata/photos/$rand_dir_name');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Here is the problem';
    }
}
```

but it doesn't create the directory. Both are in the same .php script so..where is the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
SOLVED!!!!!!!This form was inside another form!
```

Comment: `mkdir('userdata/photos/$rand_dir_name');` should be `mkdir('userdata/photos/ ' . $rand_dir_name);`

Comment: Or mkdir("userdata/photos/$rand_dir_name")...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your $rand_dir_name outside the quotes or in double quotes:

```
mkdir('userdata/photos/'.$rand_dir_name);
```

or

```
mkdir("userdata/photos/$rand_dir_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this

```
mkdir('userdata/photos/$rand_dir_name');
```

You need to do

```
mkdir('userdata/photos/' . $rand_dir_name);
```

Otherwise it will try to create a directory called "$rand_dir_name" which I'm guessing doesn't work because its invalid

Comment: Following your examples I did this `mkdir('userdata/profile_pics/'.$rand_dir_name);` and still doesn't work. I tested it with an echo and it doesn't show the echo so there is a problem in submit, but I can't see it

Comment: Also check the permissions of the `photos` directory

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with your variable in the mkdir. It should be:

```
mkdir('userdata/photos/'.$rand_dir_name);
```

Comment: there is a submit problem.. `if(($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))
 {
  /* $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
  mkdir('userdata/profile_pics/'.$rand_dir_name); */
  echo'test';
  
  
 }` it doesn't show the echo

Comment: @Angel Isnt there a space between echo and 'test' needed? This doesn't match your original question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, put

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` above everything else.

A couple of things to look out for:

- do the directories exist between this file and where you want to create the directory?
- are those directories writable by the server? (if not, you'll get a permission denied error)
- if you want to create the directories recursively (create all that are needed), you need to use `mkdir( $path, 0777, true );`

In your case it would be `mkdir( "userdata/photos/{$rand_dir_name}", 0777, true);`

The doublequotes are important, because then php can evaluate expressions inside. The {} are important because that signifies that there's something to be evaluated inside. 0777 is the default value of permissions in `mkdir` (if omitted, that's used), `true` tells mkdir to create interim folders.

References:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (for the quotes)